# Ubuntu 18.04 Xeon E5450 on p43-a7 socket 775 only one core working

Tags: cpu, multi-core

I am new to Ubuntu, so i screwed something and idk what. After manually installing nvidia drivers, my Ubuntu recognize only one of four cpu cores.

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               23
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5450  @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            6
CPU MHz:             2771.446
BogoMIPS:            5979.84
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to flash new bios and put xeon microcodes for socet 775. If you need details on how to do it, just ask here and i will walk you through.